# Boxplots from 3 different datasets in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I have data from 3 different studies. Study A has 21 samples, StudyB has 9 samples and Study C has 12 samples. Now I want to see the value distribution all samples plotted using Boxplots in R. I used the following command

```
boxplot(A,add=F,at=1:21)
boxplot(B,add=T,at=22:30)
boxplot(C,add=T,at=31:42)
```

I can only see the 21 samples from study A while 9 samples from Study B and 12 samples from Study C are not visible  and they are not fitting into the frame. I want all 42 samples from all Studies in a single frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have a look at the `xlim` argument of `boxplot` (otherwise your `B` and `C` data.frame are outside the plot area):

```
set.seed(1)
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100)

boxplot(a, at=1, xlim=c(0, 3))
boxplot(b, at=2, add=TRUE)
```

[image: boxplots]

Comment: why not `boxplot(list(a=a,b=b))`? Done in one, with informative labels.

Comment: @Spacedman: My mind was affected by OP's code. IMHO the `formula`-answer of @Thomas is the better one.

Comment: Yeah, esp if your data is in that long format, which is usually the best way to have it.

Comment: How to add custom labels to x-axis in this particular scheme?

Comment: Just add them via `axis` (see `?axis`), e.g.:  `axis(1, at=1:2, labels=c("A", "B"))`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the formula option in `boxplot`:

```
A <- rnorm(21)
B <- rnorm(9)
C <- rnorm(12)
mydf <- data.frame(y=c(A,B,C),x=c(rep(1,length(A)),rep(2,length(B)),rep(3,length(C))))
with(mydf, boxplot(y~x))
```

[image: sample plot]